# Push alerts from Prometheus/Grafana into DB

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager

We are using Prometheus/Grafana with our Microservices, most of them are Spring Boot but not all. We are going to push some alerts (according configuration) to SQL DB. I know there are such possibility to send email, slack message etc. from Prometheus/Grafana according some configuration.
Is it possible to do the same but send to DB?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to push notifications from alertmanager straight into db.

But you can utilize the webhook capabilities of alertmanger: create your own receiver, that will put all alerts into the database of your choosing. On GitHub there is a [topic](https://github.com/topics/alertmanager-webhook), that might be helpful.